How can I determine from within an instance shutdown script, that it is being deleted?
I have a shutdown script that runs on a GCE Windows instance. I want to apply different logic if the instance is being deleted, rather than just shut down or restarted. I was hoping to find a property on the instance meta-data to do this, but I haven't seen anything so far. I have also tried checking the instance resource API, but don't see anything to help me there either.
How can I determine, from within an instance shutdown script, that it is being deleted?

I don't know the answer. I am not aware of anything sent to the VM via metadata or via shutdown scripts that will tell you the instance is being deleted. That detail is logged to Cloud Logging. However, I am not sure if the log entry is created first or after a delete operation starts. Edit your question with more details: OS, what you are trying to accomplish (execute actions, save disk data, etc). IIRC the delete action creates two log entries. The first entry is created when the delete operation starts and a second entry with the final status. Perhaps design that all shutdowns are deletes.

You cannot really directly determine from within a shutdown script that the instance is being deleted. However, using gcloud compute instance-groups managed list-instances will give you an output of the current actions on instances with the column "ACTION" and there are statuses like RESTARTING, STOPPING, or DELETING.

IIRC the status DELETING occurs after the instance is shutdown. Therefore an instance cannot see that state for itself.
